# How to create a self-signed client-certificate without a CA?

Tags: certificates

I tried A lot of articles online generating certificates using openssl, but unfortunately none of them worked for me :(

There is a website that everytime I visit throws me this error:

> Sorry, but you need to provide a client certificate to continue.

I do not have the CA certificate to generate myself a client-side certificate . As of yet All I have is using:

```
curl --insecure -v https://10.10.10.131/ 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* Server certificate:/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }'
```

The output I get is:

```
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=abc; O=D E F
*  start date: Jan 27 08:35:30 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 24 08:35:30 2029 GMT
*  issuer: CN=abc; O=D E F
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.38 left intact
```

Is there somehow to generate my own client-certificate that would be accepted by the server without any CA?

Server is running `Node.js Express framework`
Client is at Kali Linux Environment.

Comment: FYI awk supports a from-pred,to-pred syntax similar to sed's from-addr,to-addr so you could more simply do `awk '/Server certificate:/,0'{if(/^\*/)print}'`

Comment: Also more substantively 'self-signed' is a term of art in PKI and means a cert signed by the key in the cert, i.e. issuer=subject, so a self-signed entity certs can never be CA-signed, making your title tautological. If you create a CA and use it to issue a client cert to yourself, that cert is (effectively) signed by you yourself, but it is not self-signed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there somehow to generate my own client-certificate that would be accepted by the server without any CA?

In general no. A client certificate is required by a server for authentication of the client. It is in a way similar to a username and password. The idea of creating your own client certificate which should be accepted by the server is similar to the idea that you can just make up your own username and password and the server will just accept it (without having a user with this name and password).

In practice there might be servers which don't actually care what certificate was send or accept even if no certificate was send. These are usually either misconfigured or require some additional authentication in case the provided certificate does not match their expectations.

If you run your own server you could of course configure it so that it accepts arbitrary certificates. And there are [lots of sites out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+self+signed+certificate+openssl) which show how to create a self-signed certificates. The instructions there have nothing to do with what you show in your question though so I'm not sure what you really tried.

Comment: Looking at the cert used by this particular server, as displayed by `curl` in the Q, it does look like the sort of server that very well might accept arbitrary/meaningless client certs.